# How to Trigger a Server-Side Event Without using HTML Forms

Tags: php, html

I am going to include a language selection multi-selector on a login page. I want the server to be notified when an item is selected and change the page language accordingly. How can I do that without using html forms?
I don't see how this can be done via a HTML form, because HTML forms do not have selection-type inputs. So, without a form at our disposal, is there any other way to send a client selection to the server?

Comment: HTML forms have selection type. `<select>`

Comment: If you're not submitting a form, you can use AJAX to send a message to the server.

Comment: You can set a cookie, this will be included when you send a form or click a link.

Comment: Thank you very much @Barmar and Akintunde007. Good points

Comment: Use ajax and javascript